# How to choose a best sampling rate, according to time constant or bandwidth?

Tags: control-engineering

This is a follow up question of [Rule of thumb for choosing a best sampling rate](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32099/rule-of-thumb-for-choosing-a-best-sampling-rate)

I have a discrete control system with a reference input. The goal is to keep the output close to the reference input (like a room temperature control system). The difference between the output and the reference input is the error fed back to the controller, forming a closed loop.

The system has a dead time, as well as a time constant, both at the scale of 1 to 10μs. I have found the open-loop transfer function $G(s)$, and derived that the bandwidth is at the scale of $10^4$ rad/s. The fastest sampling interval of the output is at the sacle of 0.1μs.
The noisy of the input can be neglected, and the control accuracy is not very strict.

I want to find out an optimal, or at least good, sampling interval. Till now I find two rules to choose the sampling interval:

1. Sample time should be at least 10 times smaller than the time constant, as I decribed in the previous question [Rule of thumb for choosing a best sampling rate](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32099/rule-of-thumb-for-choosing-a-best-sampling-rate)
2. The sampling frequency should be between 20 to 40 of the bandwidth, which can be found in many papers and books.

As these two rules lead to different sampling interval (0.1μs to 1μs by rule 1 and ~10μs by rule 2), which rule should I take?

Comment: That which works best for your application.

Comment: @SolarMike Well that's right. But as a well developed science and engineering subject, I want to see some guidlines and discussions in this case.

Comment: So you should make the effort of analysing the situations, showing them and then we might discuss your conclusions - this is not a free work service...

Comment: @SolarMike That's also right. But I'm suprised that no one in control engineering has encountered this question before. You can see this is a new account, and I have been working on this question for merely 2 days. Seems I am on my own now.

Comment: "Seems I am on my own"... You have been given some very useful hints and a good answer.

Comment: You might also ask yourself this question: Is the controller more likely to fail catastrophically and/or be unstable when I under-sample or when I over-sample the (otherwise perfect) incoming signal?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer With these two rules, I am going to test the sampling interval at different time scales(0.1 to 1 μs, and 10μs), and see how large the PV deviates from the reference point. Thanks~

Comment: Try steps 0.1, 0.3, 1, 3, 10, and 30 micro seconds. This covers two orders of magnitude with increments about half way at each step on a log scale. Plot deviation at each step to see the trend.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Got it.